# Placing a label to over of tableview

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add a label to over to tableview. I am dragging a label but it is automaticly placing to bottom left of prototype cell. How can I prevent this? I want to put this label over the tableview and it should be placed to center of screen.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You want to fix label position? i.e. label must not scroll with tableview?

Comment: Yes i want to place it as fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the placement you desire is to set the tableview to not installed. This will allow you to place the label in the position you wish above the greyed out (uninstalled) table view. Once you have added constraints to centre the label, you can reinstall the tableview. Uninstalling and installing the table view is achieved by selecting the checkbox in the attribute inspector on the right side of the Xcode window as shown below:

[image: View Installed Checkbox]

Comment: There is no Installed option in Xcode 9. How should this work there?

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the left side of interface builder there is a drop down menu for your view controller. You can move around UI elements with this drop down menu. If your label is automatically positioned inside the tableView when you drag it into the view, go into the drop down menu for the tableView and drag the label outside of the tableView and into the main view. Please note the screen shot that I have attached. In your case, you would want the label to appear below the tableView in the drop down menu so that the label is in front of the tableView.

[image]

Comment: I have a `UITableViewController` which does not show a `View` in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Use titleForHeaderInSection:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "text"
}
```